# Does an Android Activity with android.intent.category.INFO appear in places other than the play store?

Tags: android, android-intent

I found [this article](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-apps-info-category/) on providing an "info activity" to apps that have no launcher icons.

The article talks about creating an Activity with android.intent.category.INFO instead of android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, which will have the following effect:

> If you use the category android.intent.category.INFO instead of the usual LAUNCHER category then Google Play will show an "Open" button leading to this activity.

This is the documentation for android.intent.category.INFO:

> Provides information about the package it is in; typically used if a package does not contain a CATEGORY_LAUNCHER to provide a front-door to the user without having to be shown in the all apps list.

The documentation says nothing about the Play store.

Are Activities that have android.intent.category.INFO accessible from other places as well? For example, from places in the OS itself?

Comment: I don't understand your question. All activities are accessible (assuming that they are "enabled" and "exported" (either explicitly or implicitly). Please explain exactly what you want to know.

Comment: I not talking about the fact that exported Activities can be started from different apps via code. I'm asking if there are places other than the Google Play store where users can get to Activities with android.intent.category.INFO appear. For example with another intent filter - an Activity with action android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES is accessible from an app's info screen (settings->apps->app).

Answer (score 2):

`android.intent.category.INFO` is also used when the user installs the APK directly (no app store or ADB.) When the installation finish screen is shown there are two options "Done" and "Open". Pressing "Open" will open the activity with the `INFO` category. It will even override any activities with `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`, so only use it if your app doesn't have a launcher. I discovered this on Android 8.1, but it probably does it on older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Are Activities that have android.intent.category.INFO accessible from
>   other places as well?

Well, from android studio, when you try to run the app on device/emulator - and if this activity is your "main" activity, the Android studio will complain that "**Default Activity Not found"** - this means that for "tools" such as Android studio - it's not available as "launcher"

You can still install the APK from command line - for example using -  `adb install -r -t app-debug.apk`